# jquery tabs - repeater itemcommand not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, tabs, repeater

I am using jquery tabs and on my page have few tabs...on one of the pages have added repeater and binding etc works fine as it is on load.

but when I try to bind Itemcommand event of repeater it doesn't fire and I get this error in firebug:

```
Timestamp: 30/10/2012 10:37:35
Error: TypeError: theForm.__EVENTTARGET is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:53351/Default.aspx
Line: 8
```

and line 8 is my reference to jquery :

`<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If I remove this obviously there is not tabs and I get redirected to my orginal page with no tab and the event works fine. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue was due to postback being disabled on Jquery tab.